# How to get emitter particles to stay static?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm trying to animate my first blender render (https://www.instagram.com/p/B6zkzSTDqiC/) and having trouble gettings the particles to stay put. The bushes next to the entrances of the building are created by particles (from a sphere object) and when I start the animation, they automatically fall down because of the gravity of the scene. So a question here: is there a way to have the bush particles stay on the sphere when I start the animation?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and **use the tools from this site to upload images** so that they are displayed as part of your question and not as a link to a different site. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you won't need all of these, but to stay on the safe side:

1. the ***Start* and *End*** time of the particle *Emission* must be `1` (all particles emitted at the first frame) and their ***Lifetime*** must be `250` (or the animation length in frames)
2. the ***Velocity*** must be `0` in each one of its components. Including  ***Normal***, that is `1` by default!
3. ***Physics Type*** should be set to `None`
4. the ***Field Weights*** called ***Gravity* and *All*** must be `0` (this is redundant, since *Physics*: `None` should guarantee this already)

To summarize:

[image]

(*Hair* particles, on the other hand, won't move by default. Unless *Hair Dynamics* is selected; in which case, deselect it.)